# Fonts and livewire failed on Laravel on kubernetes pods

Tags: php, laravel, kubernetes

Laravel 10
Livewire 2

I have a Laravel application that I deployed to Kubernetes. Everything works fine except the following things:

- Livewire is loaded, but when I use a component that uses it, it shows me an error in a modal window (404 error)
- Fonts in app.css (located in `public/css`) are not loaded with the correct URL (but other static files like `.img` are loaded fine). The path defined in the ingress and in APP_URL is not used (`/service/myapplication/`)

I put the following in the `app.php` and `livewire.php` files:

```php
'asset_url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
'app_url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
```

My entry rule:

```yaml
rules:
  - host: mydomain.env.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myapplication
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /service/myapplication/(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
```

How can I resolve this issue?

I've tried a lot of things like `php artisan` to clear caches, change my APP_URL variable etc... Nothing seems to work.

Comment: "it shows me an error" What does that error say?

Comment: @ceejayoz a 404 error

Comment: @ceejayoz if I look in logs, I've the following : "POST /livewire/message/mymessage"

Comment: Am I correct in thinking `/service/myapplication/livewire/message/mymessage` is where you want it to be accessing?  If so, you may need to use `Livewire::setUpdateRoute`. https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/installation#configuring-livewires-update-endpoint

Comment: @ceejayoz I've edited my question. Your solution is for Livewire 3 but I use Livewire 2 today. So unfortunately, it doesn't work for me.